# Как послать запрос авторизации в vk.com?

Tags: вконтакте

Здравствуйте!
Пишу свой клиент для vk. Изучаю что и как работает...
Не могу понять как отправить запрос для авторизации.
у них есть vk.com/dev/methods . Но тыкаюсь уже пол дня, фиг знает что не так.
Никак не могу авторизоваться... Лучшее, что смог найти: `https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=1914441&...=***&username=***&password=***`

Но тут нужен id приложения, еще что-то...
Кто может обьяснить что им нужно туда отправить для авторизации?
Неужели нельзя так: vk.com/login=***%pass=*** - всё! Что мудрить?

Comment: @Alerr вот из-за таких как вы "мудрецов" половина сайтов дырявые. Есть понятие [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), vk как и любой нормальный сайт использует эту идеологию. Правда, словосочетание vk==нормальный сайт - вызывает у меня гомерический хохот

Comment: Вопрос в том, как послать,(какой строчкой) запрос на авторизацию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

регистрируете приложение https://vk.com/editapp?act=create

авторизуетесь https://vk.com/dev/authentication

получаете адрес сервера для загрузки изображения https://vk.com/dev/photos.getWallUploadServer

Сохраняете загруженную фотографию https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveWallPhoto

публикуете запись на стене https://vk.com/dev/wall.post

Comment: Спасибо) Четко и по теме). Вопрос, обязательно создавать\регистрировать приложение? Без приложения никак? Могут ли другие люди установить это приложение и будет оно выполнять те же заложенные в него функции?

Comment: Да. так как без него Вы не сможете работать с API.
А работа напрямую, минуя API вроде как запрещена правилами сайта.

Comment: Всё получилось!!! Только в браузере в строке адреса появляется access_tocken, а программно я его что-то не могу отловить... Приходит какая-то фигня, не содержащяя ацесс токена(

Comment: есть 2 варианта получения токена, 1 напрямую (параметр response_type=token в URL https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile), 2 - через code (https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites)

Answer (score 0):

Читайте инструкцию в специальном для этого разделе на сайте.

https://vk.com/dev

Comment: Читал, я так понял, что нужно написать\создать свое приложение в ВК и с ним как-то стыковаться... Но мне этого не надо. Мне надо залогиниться, передать файл-картинку и вывести сообщение на странице с этой картинкой.

Comment: @Alerr, прочитайте внимательно статью http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Comment: @Alerr, учитесь читать.